# Composite images with ImageMagick convert

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to automatically compose (overlay) two PNG image files. I have a background image and a mostly transparent overlay of the same dimensions. The latter contains text on transparent background.

When doing

```
convert "$background.png" "$foreground.png" -composite +antialias "$output.png"
```

I obtain an output file in which the text has thin grey outlines. I suspected that it was due to anti-aliasing turned on by default and tried to add the switch `+antialias`. This does not seem to change anything. There seems to be a large number of methods for the merging to be specified with `-compose`. I am lost and do not know which of these make sense, if any.

I also tried `composite` which is discribed here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/ .

Comment: If the name of the pictures you deal with,  are `background.png` `foreground.png` ... and those are not variables, try to  strip the `$` and write `convert "background.png" "foreground.png" -composite +antialias "output.png"`.

Comment: They are variables.

Comment: Can you add the files that give you this problem? That method in general works, as you state it is probably something in your files... without it is difficult to find a solution. Please add the imagemagick version too.

Comment: I struggled a bit trying to create a working example because it is a subtle effect which however destroys the readability of the handwritten text images I am merging. While experimenting I discovered that ` -layers merge` seems to do what I need. What is the difference compared to `-composite`?